# Is there a way to get information about the callers volume level using Twilio's API?

Tags: volume, twilio

Im trying to display each caller on a conference lines volume in our product.  I was looking through Twilio's API docs and dont see anything around this.  Does anyone know if theres a way to display the volume of each caller so you know which person to mute once you are dialed in through a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here. Unfortunately it is not possible at the moment to determine the volume level of a call using Twilio but I have passed the feature request on to our product team!